# How can I hide the eject icons from nautilus sidebar for permanently-mounted drives?

Tags: nautilus, fstab, eject

I have two RAID arrays that are fstab-mounted. They are as important to me as the root disk as a large portion of my home dir is mounted from one of these arrays.

Here's how they look in the nautilus sidebar:

[image]

When I click one of these eject icons, it errors out (I'd need to be root) but that's by-the-by, I don't want the icon there in the first place.

Is there anything I can do to suppress it for certain drives? It needs to be targeted because I still want to be able to unmount SD cards, my phone, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, if the drive is not unmountable by the user no eject button should be shown. That the button *is* shown regardless of whether it is useful or not has been reported as a bug here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586644

Answer (score 2):

If your mount point is not under /media, but for example under /mnt, the icon will not be showed.

Comment: +1. '/media' is defined as mount point for removable media in the filesystem hierarchy standard: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf

Comment: Will the device still be listed by nautilus at all?

Comment: @Oli No, you can access the device through Filesystem /, then /mnt

Comment: @htorque By that same document `/mnt/` is described: "This directory is provided so that the system administrator may temporarily mount a filesystem as needed. The
content of this directory is a local issue and should not affect the manner in which any program is run." My mounts are not temporary and unmounting them will have a profound and very much severe effect on running programs.

Comment: @enzotib I'd rather have the eject icon than have to go hunting for the drives.

Comment: @Oli It seems that the doc do not provide an indication to where to mount non-removable media. I would not limit my possibilities because a doc say so, specially if I am the only admin of my machine, and I know what I am doing. If I would be particularly careful, I would create a /my-mnt dir and use that. But these are only my opinions, and you are welcome to take your own decision based on what you feel right.

Comment: You could add the mount points as bookmarks - not a perfect solution, of course. The problem is, that _you_ need to tell the system if the filesystem is removable or not, and AFAIK there's no other way to do so than mounting removable filesystems in /media and non-removable filesystems somewhere else. Personally I just deal with those icons as I cannot eject those mounts anyway.